# Facebook: lightweight version of JavaScript SDK?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I wish to implement Facebook login on my mobile application (mainly JavaScript + HTML5). However, I would like to avoid adding the entire JavaScript SDK to the application. It weights approximately 150 kb minified due to all that UI stuff and other bells and whistles, it is just too much overhead for a mobile app. It is possible to get a limited version of SDK with only certain features included? Like Modernizr, jQuery UI, etc.

Alternatively, is there a third-party implementation of Facebook authentication in JavaScript that sets the correct cookies, etc?

Answer (score 0):

try this Facebook Javascript SDK, it's only 44.4kb (much smaller than the one you're using).  Find the complete documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

```
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
```

Comment: On my machine it is 44.4kb according to Firebug in Firefox and chrome reports it as 44.91kb.  However on silly IE, it reports it as 146.6kb.  So I'd suggest switching to a browser that doesn't need so many extra bytes in the code to get it to work correctly.

Comment: Perhaps 44.4kb while GZipped. I just saved the file on my machine (using Chrome) and checked its size -- it is 150 kb.

Comment: I did the same thing, it's 150kb on my machine too, when I downloaded it.  I don't think there's an argument here at all; the file is clearly smaller when it's gzipped and around 150kb when it's not.  I believe the question is, is it possible to get a smaller version that doesn't have as much functionality, similar to how you can download a customized version of twitter-bootstrap.